# react.js antd carousel with arrows

Tags: reactjs, carousel, antd

I am looking at using the antd Caroseul, but I've not seen an example that creates a prev/next or pause button.

```
const { Carousel } = antd;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Carousel autoplay>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  </Carousel>
, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Just need to add "arrows" next to autoplay param

Answer (score 28):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Carousel, Icon } from "antd";

export default class CarouselComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
    this.carousel = React.createRef();
  }
  next() {
    this.carousel.next();
  }
  previous() {
    this.carousel.prev();
  }

  render() {
    const props = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Icon type="left-circle" onClick={this.previous} />
        <Carousel ref={node => (this.carousel = node)} {...props}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
        <Icon type="right-circle" onClick={this.next} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so that the other developer knows the answer too.

Answer (score 17):

First of all: `arrow` is a valid Carousel property that enables the arrows to manually control the content.
It is [disabled by default](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5458) by antd.

You can enable it like this:

```
<Carousel arrows>
//
</Carousel>
```

But you won't see them because the style for `.ant-carousel .slick-prev` and `.ant-carousel .slick-prev` is transparent.

[image: style for antd carousel arrows default]

At this point you already can override the style (example `display: block; background: red`).

---

Another option is to control the style from inside the prop, using [React Slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) properties, since antd is using it under the hood for the Carousel component.

This is a full component example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Carousel } from 'antd'

const contentStyle = {
  height: '160px',
  color: '#fff',
  lineHeight: '160px',
  textAlign: 'center',
  background: '#364d79'
}

// from https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows
const SampleNextArrow = props => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: 'block', background: 'red' }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  )
}

const SamplePrevArrow = props => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: 'block', background: 'green' }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  )
}

const settings = {
  nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
  prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
}

const CarouselArrows = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Row justify="center">
        <Col span={16}>
          <Carousel arrows {...settings}>
            <div>
              <h3 style={contentStyle}>1</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3 style={contentStyle}>2</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3 style={contentStyle}>3</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3 style={contentStyle}>4</h3>
            </div>
          </Carousel>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}

export default CarouselArrows
```

[image: arrows example]

---

There is a `::before` selector with `content` property that kinda screws up the style (you can't override it from inline style).
You could take advantage of it though and change the arrow functions to:

```
const SampleNextArrow = props => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: 'block', background: 'red' }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  )
}

const SamplePrevArrow = props => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: 'block', background: 'green' }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  )
}
```

[image]

---

You can override the default antd style to remove the `::before` selector and include icons.

In a LESS file:

```css
.ant-carousel {
  .slick-next {
    &::before {
      content: '';
    }
  }
  .slick-prev { 
    &::before {
      content: '';
    }
  }
}
```

And in your component (implying that you're using the component provided in the example above):

```
import { LeftOutlined, RightOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'

// ...

const SampleNextArrow = props => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{
        ...style,
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: '15px',
        lineHeight: '1.5715'
      }}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <RightOutlined />
    </div>
  )
}

const SamplePrevArrow = props => {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{
        ...style,
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: '15px',
        lineHeight: '1.5715'
      }}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <LeftOutlined />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Finally, the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**just follow this code :**
use useRef hook and assign a Ref to Carousel and then call next and prev method by refrence.

```
import React, { useRef, Fragment } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "antd";

const MyCarousel = () => {
const slider = useRef(null);

return ( 
<Fragment >
    <Button onClick={() => slider.current.next()}>next</Button>
    <Carousel ref={slider}>
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
    </Carousel>
    <Button onClick={() => slider.current.next()}>next</Button>
</Fragment >
)}
```

Comment: For me this didn't worked (my program crashed because it couldn't find the function). So instead I had to declare  `let slider = useRef(null)` . Then in the carousel I had to call the ref like this: `<Carousel { ...settings } ref={ node => slider = node } ...`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add arrows, you can use the arrow icons provided by Antd

```
<Carousel arrows nextArrow={<ArrowRightOutlined />} prevArrow={<ArrowLeftOutlined/>}>
```

Since the arrows are hidden by Antd css, you can override it in your own css with the following:

```
.ant-carousel .slick-prev,
.ant-carousel .slick-next {
  color: unset;
  font-size: unset;
}

.ant-carousel .slick-prev:hover,
.ant-carousel .slick-next:hover,
.ant-carousel .slick-prev:focus,
.ant-carousel .slick-next:focus {
  color: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Whilst reading https://ant.design/components/carousel/ I scrolled to the bottom and it says that it's using https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

If you scroll down to the `prop` table, you can use `nextArrow` or `prevArrow` which takes a React Element as a value.

Comment: Thank you. Is `nextArrow` or `prevArrow` what is called `arrows` on react-slick docs at https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#arrows ? I guess it's the same `arrows` object for both left and right arrows. Where do I put `arrows` within the AntD Carousel code?

Comment: Kindly display a props type example here for arrows implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the **React Hooks**. I just found the result.
 Here is example:

```
function SampleNextArrow(props) {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props
    return (
        <div
        className={className}
        style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "red" }}
        onClick={onClick}
        />
    )
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props
    return (
        <div
        className={className}
        style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "green" }}
        onClick={onClick}
        />
    )
}

const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 8,
    nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
}

<Carousel {...settings} arrows={true} draggable={true}>
    {koompiApps.map((res, index) => {
        return (
        <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={24} xl={24}>
            <div
            onClick={(e) => {
                setAppsKey(`${index + 1}`)
            }}
            >
            <center>
                <motion.div
                whileHover={{
                    scale: 1.1,
                    transition: { duration: 0.3 },
                }}
                whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
                >
                <img
                    src={`${res.logo}`}
                    className="koompiApps "
                    alt={res.name}
                />
                <h4 className="appsName">{res.name}</h4>
                </motion.div>
            </center>
            </div>
        </Col>
        )
    })}
</Carousel>
```

**The Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set prop `arrows` be true, and the next and prev arrow should appear. But you cannot see it because antd css set it to be transparent, you can feel them by hovering the mouse on.

To make them visible, you can install slick-carousel npm, and import the css:

```
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme";
```

then set the arrow css like:

```
.ant-carousel .slick-arrow::before {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'slick';
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we pass `arrows` to **Carousel**, it actually works, but the main problem is with CSS, because the default `font-size` of `slick-prev` and `slick-next` is `0px`.

The same problem exists with `slick-prev::before` and `slick-next::before`

I can recommend this option, which will simply change the default style's.
Thanks

```js
 <Carousel autoplay arrows>
  <div>Test1</div>
  <div>Test2</div>
</Carousel>
```

```css
.slick-arrow.slick-prev {
  font-size: 10px;
  
}
.ant-carousel .slick-prev::before {
    content: '<';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 3px;
    /* width: 100px; */
    font-size: 25px;
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
   
}
.slick-arrow.slick-next {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.ant-carousel .slick-next::before {
  content: '>';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 20px;
  /* width: 100px; */
  font-size: 25px;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Code only dumps are discouraged on SO.  Please consider editing to highlight key parts of your solution & explain how/why that addressed the OP's issue. Most upvotes for quality posts are accrued over time, as future visitors learn something from your post to apply to their own coding issues. It also lends better to SO's mission of being a place to collaborate, share knowledge & learn, rather than giving the impression of being simply a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
import { Image } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Image.PreviewGroup>
    <Image width={200} src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/KDpgvguMpGfqaHPjicRK.svg" />
    <Image
      width={200}
      src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/antfincdn/aPkFc8Sj7n/method-draw-image.svg"
    />
  </Image.PreviewGroup>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace it with any ant design icon

```
//import
import { createFromIconfontCN, LeftOutlined, RightOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

//definition
const SlickArrowLeft = ({ currentSlide, slideCount, ...props }) => (
  <button
    {...props}
    className={
      "slick-prev slick-arrow" +
      (currentSlide === 0 ? " slick-disabled" : "")
    }
    aria-hidden="true"
    aria-disabled={currentSlide === 0 ? true : false}
    type="button"
  >
    <LeftOutlined />
  </button>
);
const SlickArrowRight = ({ currentSlide, slideCount, ...props }) => (
  <button
    {...props}
    className={
      "slick-next slick-arrow" +
      (currentSlide === slideCount - 1 ? " slick-disabled" : "")
    }
    aria-hidden="true"
    aria-disabled={currentSlide === slideCount - 1 ? true : false}
    type="button"
  >
    <RightOutlined />
  </button>
);

//use 
<Carousel
{...settings}
prevArrow={<SlickArrowLeft />}
nextArrow={<SlickArrowRight />}
>
```