# React antd carousel methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am looking at using the `antd` Carousel, but I've not seen an example that describes how to use `goTo(slideNumber, dontAnimate)` method.

I have tried to use answers on this question [react.js antd carousel with arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114224/react-js-antd-carousel-with-arrows) to make `goTo` method works for me, but it didn't help, I always get carousel ref as `null`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
import { Modal, Carousel } from 'antd'

export default class ImagePreviewCarousel extends React.Component<any, any> {

    carousel = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.carousel);
    }

    render() {
        const { url, imgList } = this.props;
        const orderLayout = document.getElementById('order-layout');
        const applicationLayout = document.getElementById('application');

        return (
            createPortal(<ImageViewer url={url} onClose={this.props.onClose} imgList={imgList} />, orderLayout || applicationLayout)
        )
    }
}

const ImageViewer = (props: IProps) => {
    return (
        <Modal 
            footer={null} 
            visible={props.onClose} 
            onCancel={props.onClose}
            bodyStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#000' }}
            width={'800px'}
        >
            <div style={{
                display: 'flex', 
                flexDirection: 'column', 
                justifyContent: 'center', 
                marginTop: 'auto', 
                marginBottom: 'auto', 
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%', 
                zIndex: 10
            }}>
                <Carousel ref={node => (this.carousel = node)}>
                    {props.imgList}
                </Carousel>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

result of `console.log(this.carousel)` always returns `null`, what am i doing wrong?

p.s react version 16.4.1,

Comment: Have your problem solved?

Comment: unfortunately not, any ideas?@DennisVash

Comment: Check out my answer hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[antd `Carousel`](https://ant.design/components/carousel/) is an implementation of `react-slick`, you can [check its API example](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slick-go-to).

Here is [my example](https://1kli9.codesandbox.io/) using hooks:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Carousel, Row, InputNumber } from 'antd';


function App() {
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState(0);

  const slider = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Row style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <InputNumber
          min={0}
          max={3}
          value={slide}
          onChange={e => {
            setSlide(e);
            slider.current.goTo(e);
          }}
        />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Carousel
          dots={false}
          ref={ref => {
            console.log(ref);
            slider.current = ref;
          }}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>0</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56935749-Carousel]

Comment: Nice, i accept your solution , but unfortunately in my work project we dont use hooks  ;( So, if you will find better solution without hooks please let me know =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `ref` to your child component like,

```
<ImageViewer url={url} onClose={this.props.onClose} imgList={imgList} onRef={this.carousel} />
```

And can access in child component like,

```
<Carousel ref={props.onRef}>
       {props.imgList}
</Carousel>
```

While printing in `componentDidMount`,

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.carousel); // If this gives you ref object 
   console.log(this.carousel.current); //This will give you element
   console.log(this.carousel.current.value); //This will give you element's value if element has value.
}
```

Simplified [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-27rug?fontsize=14) using input.

Comment: Thank you, I have done exactly as you told me but I got this strange result in console  http://prntscr.com/oc54gx (first result null but with info that value was evaluated just now), dont you know why this happened?

Comment: You will get reference to carousal using `this.carousal.current`. You are getting `{current:null}` because usually it returns HTML Element and `Carousal` is not HTML Element.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.carousel) - returns {current: null} (but as a told higher with info that value was evaluated just now)
        console.log(this.carousel.current) - returns null 
    }

Comment: instead of Carousel, can you try to add ref on Carousel Item like `<Carousel ><div ref={props.onRef}>{props.imgList}</div></Carousel>` . Also make sure if `imgList` is array then iterate the same using `Array.map`.

Comment: ref on div (`<Carousel ><div ref={props.onRef}>{props.imgList}</div></Carousel>`)  still returns null =(

Comment: What does `props.imgList` looks like?

Comment: `const imageListToCarousel = images.map((image, index) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <Image>
                        <StyledImg src={image} key={index} />
                    </Image>
                </>
            )
        });`

Comment: You must iterate `props.imgList` like, `<Carousel >{props.imgList.map(image => <div ref={props.onRef}>{image}</div>)}</Carousel>`

Comment: @JANEDOE I was using a normal Carousel in my demo, just check out the demo added by me it is working now. No need to move ref to child component, You can have `<Carousel ref={props.onRef}>
       {props.imgList}
</Carousel>` Check out the Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-27rug?fontsize=14

Comment: @JANEDOE Have you checked the demo?