# Using Ant Design's carousel next and previous pane methods in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using Ant Design as the design framework for my application.
The framework has a [Carousel](https://ant.design/components/carousel/) component, the component exposes two methods to switch panes in the carousel.

Here's an example to utilize it in [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114224/react-js-antd-carousel-with-arrows).

Here's my attempt to do it using Typescript:

```
interface State {
  slider: ReactNode;
}

interface Props {}

class ImageCarousel extends Component<Props, State> {
  private carousel: any;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.carousel = React.createRef();
  }

  nextPane() {
    this.carousel.next();
  }
  prevPane() {
    this.carousel.prev();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CarouselWrapper>
        <RegularButtonWrapper>
          <RegularButton
            size="large"
            icon="caret-left"
            onClick={this.prevPane}
          />
        </RegularButtonWrapper>
        <FlexCarousel>
          <Carousel
            ref={node => (this.carousel = node)}
            speed={700}
            effect="fade"
            autoplay
            autoplaySpeed={3000}
          >
            <img src={IU} />
            <img src={IU2} />
            <img src={IU3} />
            <img src={IU4} />
            <img src={IU5} />
          </Carousel>
        </FlexCarousel>
        <RegularButtonWrapper>
          <RegularButton
            size="large"
            icon="caret-right"
            onClick={this.nextPane}
          />
        </RegularButtonWrapper>
      </CarouselWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageCarousel;
```

The above doesn't work - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'carousel' of undefined`.

How can I use the methods with Typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the navigation methods on the DOM node itself by accessing the `current` property where the ref stores it. Here's a basic example. You're getting that error because you're using `this` inside of your previous/next methods, so it's actually referring to the function scope.  Try converting them to arrow functions as below (binding the methods in the constructor as mentioned in the other answer would work as well).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.carouselRef = createRef();
  }

  onChange = (a, b, c) => {
    console.log(a, b, c);
  };

  handleNext = () => this.carouselRef.current.next();

  handlePrev = () => this.carouselRef.current.prev();

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Carousel afterChange={this.onChange} ref={this.carouselRef}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
        <Button onClick={this.handlePrev}>Previous</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.handleNext}>Next</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Sanbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-breeze-jxsd4).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `this`-binding in the cronstructor from the original JS:

```
this.nextPane = this.nextPane.bind(this);
this.previousPane = this.previousPane.bind(this);
```

Comment: I tried adding it to the constructor but got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`.

Comment: Where? In the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

thanx for @Chris-B . and if you using function component in react using this code:

```
function App () {

    const carousel = useRef();

 const onChange = (a, b, c) => {
    console.log(a, b, c);
  };

 const handleNext = () => carousel.current.next();

 const handlePrev = () => carousel.current.prev();

 
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Carousel afterChange={onChange} ref={carousel}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
        <Button onClick={handlePrev}>Previous</Button>
        <Button onClick={handleNext}>Next</Button>
      </div>
    )
}
```